# I have submitted app to app store and app status came like 'Metadata Rejected' and following review status. I do not have login page

Tags: ios

> We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because
>   we need a demo account to fully access your app features.
>
> Please provide demo account details in the Review Notes section of the
>   Version Information for your app. Please ensure that the information
>   you provide includes any data necessary to demonstrate the
>   functionality of your app features.
>
> You can provide demo account information, including passwords, in the
>   Review Notes section of your iTunes Connect App Information.
>
> While your iTunes Connect Application State shows as Metadata
>   Rejected, we don't require a new binary to correct this issue. Please
>   visit iTunes Connect, Manage Your Applications. Select your app, then
>   click View Details of the desired version. Click the Edit button next
>   to Version Information to edit the Review Notes for your app, then
>   click "Save".

How do I correct the metadata? I do not have login account.

Comment: As the message from Apple clearly states, the problem isn't with the metadata - it's because they need a demo account to evaluate your app.

Comment: Are there accounts in your app? Then provide one to Apple. If there is no need for an account for any of your user, then I don't know how to make Apple evaluate your app

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail about your app?  Is it a client for your own service, or for a third-party service?

Comment: Questions like this should be asked from Apple instead

Answer (score 2):

You only need to give information For Ex.if your app start with login screen then you have to provide username and password in review notes section.

So whatever information is needed to go through your application you have to provide in review section so using that They people can evaluate your app..

And you not need to provide binary again only metadata you have to provide...